# Change site default resolution

Tags: html, css

While working one my design I found out that the css zoom property was working on chrome but not on firefox ...
I've tried to use the parameter "initial-scale=0.1" on a meta content class but it doesn't work on any browsers. 
That's important because my site is better with a default zoom of 80%. And the stuff below is only working one chrome.
So how can I change the default zoom decently ?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--<meta content="initial-scale=0.1">-->
    </head>

    <body>
        <span> blabla</span>
        <div></div>
        <style type="text/css">
            div {
                color: purple;
                width: 100px;
                height:100px;
            background-color: #d8da3d 
            }
            body {
                zoom:0.5; 
            }
        </style>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can try to use `transform: scale(0.5)` instead of zoom.

Comment: Why did you build a site that looks best at 80% zoom?

Answer (score 0):

**First**; your question says resolution.. While you mean the zoom percentage.

**Zoom**

Zoom is supported in IE, Safari 4 and Chrome.

Zoom is not supported on Opera nor Firefox.

On Firefox you can use an alternative for version 3.5 and up; `-moz-transform: scale(0.8);`
**Note;** inline elements will not force other elements to move, causing overlay.

**Conclusion**

So to make all browsers display the website the same way, i would recommand using a smaller website. You can use either px or %. (em for font)

I prefer 960px as width, since most screens are larger, and the number can be devided by many other numbers without creating a decimal number.